# Swift Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while pass image to another ViewController

Tags: swift, image, picker

I have two VCs. The first one contains an imagePicker from gallery and a callback function that sends and image to the chatLog... I want to send the selected photo to the 2nd VC

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {

        //self.callback?(selectedImage)
        detailImageViewController.aImage = selectedImage
}
```

I created the 2nd VC as controller for PreviewImage with buttons **cancel** or **accept**. I tried to pass the image displayed on the 2nd VC back to 1st VC this way but it shows me:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

How can I fix that?

```
var t : EVTPhotoTekingHelper!

@objc func actionSend() {

    if aImage != nil{
        t.callback?(aImage!)
    }
    else {
        print("nil")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**UPDATED:**

My 1st VC

```
typealias PhotoTekingHelperCallBack = (UIImage?) -> ()

class EVTPhotoTekingHelper: NSObject {

// View controller on which AlertViewController and UIImageViewController are present
weak var viewController: UIViewController!

var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController?
var callback: PhotoTekingHelperCallBack?
var photoTakinHelper: EVTPhotoTekingHelper!

// MARK: - Initialization

init(viewController: UIViewController, callback: @escaping PhotoTekingHelperCallBack) {

    self.viewController = viewController
    self.callback = callback

    super.init()

    showPhotoSourceSelection()
}

func showPhotoSourceSelection() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil,
                                                 message: "Message?",
                                                 preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "from library", style: .default) { (action) in

        self.showImagePickerController(sourceType: .photoLibrary)

    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)


    if UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailable(for: .rear) {

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "from camera", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            self.showImagePickerController(sourceType: .camera)
        })

        alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    }

    viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showImagePickerController(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {

    imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController.init()
    imagePickerController!.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePickerController!.delegate = self

    viewController.present(imagePickerController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Extension from 1st VC

```
extension EVTPhotoTekingHelper: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originImage
    }

    let detailImageViewController = EVImagePreviewController()
    let ncDetailImageViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailImageViewController)
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {

        //self.callback?(selectedImage)
        detailImageViewController.aImage = selectedImage
    }
    viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    viewController.parent?.present(ncDetailImageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

My 2nd VC

```
class EVImagePreviewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var t : EVTPhotoTekingHelper!
var aImageView: UIImageView!
var aImage: UIImage!

private var aScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    aImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: (aImage?.size.width)!, height: (aImage?.size.height)!))
    aImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    aImageView.image = aImage

    aScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
    aScrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
    aScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.height)
    aScrollView.minimumZoomScale  = 0.2
    aScrollView.maximumZoomScale  = 2.3
    aScrollView.clipsToBounds     = true
    aScrollView.delegate = self

    aScrollView.addSubview(aImageView)

    view.addSubview(aScrollView)

    aImageView.center = CGPoint(x: aScrollView.bounds.midX, y: aScrollView.bounds.midY - 35)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionSend))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionBack))

}

// MARK: - IBAction

@objc func actionBack() {

    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@objc func actionSend() {

    print("\(t)")
    if aImage != nil{
        t.callback?(aImage!)
    }
    else {
        print("nil")
    }


    //self.callback?(aImage)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return aImageView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let subView = scrollView.subviews[0]

    let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0)
    let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0)

    subView.center = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX, y: scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY)
}
}
```

Comment: How is created `detailImageViewController`? In `detailImageViewController.aImage = selectedImage`? `var t : EVTPhotoTekingHelper!` is what? The previous ViewController? If you do `print("\(t)"), does it crash?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni i check image.size.width and image.size.height... both has values... so i guess image != nil
Also my image displayed on imageView successfully so i tried to pass t.callback?(imaveView.image!)... same error

Comment: @Larme detailImageViewController is 2nd VC... EVTPhotoTekingHelper (NSObject Class) is 1st VC
print("(t)") show me nil =//

Comment: If `t` wasn’t set somewhere it remains `nil` and causes the crash.

Comment: Please update your question with theses infos, they are quite important to give context on your code. Also, could you name your variables, or at least specify what's the class name of first/previous VC, how there are created etc, how is `t` init/passed? etc.

Comment: @Larme code updated...

Comment: @Larme from 1st VC extension callback(selectedImage) works fine.. the point was to create preview of selected image and then post it to chatLog

Comment: Once again, the `t` property isn’t set nowhere in the code so accessing it causes a crash

Comment: can you add your callback implementation and specify where it is? in addition to init of EVTPhotoTekingHelper

Answer (score 0):

Here you dismiss your first view controller before you present your 2nd one from the parent of your first view controller:

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

To me so far doesn't make sense. Its not clear where is the callback implementation is.

> My guess that the nil exception is not for the UIImage for sure. its somewhere
>   inside your callback implementation.